# HTML tags using paste in R

Tags: r

Can anyone help me here with HTML tags

```
> df <- "sadfsdf adfsd"
> HTML(paste0(strwrap(glue('Comments : <span style = "font-weight:lighter">{df}</span>'),width = 50), collapse="</br>"))

Comments : <span style =</br>"font-weight:lighter">sadfsdf adfsd</span>
```

Not sure why  is coming in between.

Expected output

```
Comments : <span style ="font-weight:lighter">sadfsdf adfsd</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it to yourself with `strwrap`.

```r
strwrap(glue::glue('Comments : <span style = "font-weight:lighter">{df}</span>'),width = 50)
# [1] "Comments : <span style ="                     "\"font-weight:lighter\">sadfsdf adfsd</span>"
```

That's a length-2 vector, so by wrapping that in `paste0(..., collapse="</br>")`, you corrupt it.

```r
paste0(strwrap(glue::glue('Comments : <span style = "font-weight:lighter">{df}</span>'),width = 50), collapse="</br>")
# [1] "Comments : <span style =</br>\"font-weight:lighter\">sadfsdf adfsd</span>"
```

Further, I suspect the `strwrap` and `paste0` should be done inside of the glue, perhaps

```r
htmltools::HTML(glue::glue('Comments : <span style = "font-weight:lighter">{ paste0(strwrap(df,width=50),collapse="</br>") }</span>'))
# Comments : <span style = "font-weight:lighter">sadfsdf adfsd</span>
```